# How to make a column depend on other columns in one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

- There is a model `Pair` which consists of 3 string fields: `arr1`, `arr2`,
  `arr3`
- I input the values of `arr1` and `arr2` and
- I want `arr3` value to consist of similar numbers from `arr1` and `arr2`

  after the comparison of `arr1` and `arr2`

I'm not sure where to place **the code for comparison** `arr1` and `arr2`, because
it doens't work in the `new` method `PairsController`:

```
    @pair = Pair.find(params[:id])
    @A = @pair.arr1.split & @pair.arr2.split
    @arr3 = @A.join(" ")
```

**the output** of `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3` in a table:

```
...
<td><%= pair.arr1 %></td>
<td><%= pair.arr2 %></td>
<td><%= pair.arr3%></td>
...
```

**the input** of arr1 and arr2 in a layout:

```
...
<p><%= f.text_field :arr1 %></p>
<p><%= f.text_field :arr2 %></p>
...
```

What the table looks like now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2itg.png

Where should I place the comparison code and how to send the value to `arr3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many-many ways to do it.

For example using some callback in your model.

```
class Pair < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :set_up_arr3

  def set_up_arr3
    self.arr3 = (arr1.split & arr2.split).join(" ")
  end
end
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь! И сорри, что засоряю сайт такими школьными вопросами.